# Cannot connect to mac build host xamarin

Tags: macos, xamarin

I have two computers -  hp and macbook. I trying to connect to mac os build host and have this.

[image]

Comment: are they on different networks?  Can you ping the mac from the pc?

Comment: No, connected to same wi-fi @Jason

I see mac in list

Comment: Are you using the same version of the components on both side? Latest Xamarin.iOS completely changes the way to talk so the version must match.

Comment: how I can check xamarin iOS version on windows and mac? @LexLi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First, reboot both machine and retry (seriously, number one problem I've seen with Build Host is hung services, you can unload/load them via the cmd line, but just reboot...)
- Second, Try connecting via telnet (see below) (Failures here are the second most common thing I have seen).
- Third, Still not connecting via telnet, Turn off the firewalls on **both** machines and retry the telnet test. (If this works, open ports 5000 on both)
- Forth, I see your PC and Mac are on different subnets, place them on the same subnet and skip Wifi, direct cable them together!

**Try connecting to the build server from the Windows machine via telnet:**

- Install the Telnet Client from "Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off."

In a command prompt, run:

```
telnet "buildhost IP address" 5000
```

(Replace "buildhost IP address" with the IP address of your Mac)

Type `HELO` and press return.

*Note: HELO is intentionally spelled with just one "L".*

If everything's working correctly, the build server will reply with something like this:

```
MTBSERVERPORTS:52566;52567
```

**Note: There should be *nothing* else returned but the line above, and *nothing* before you enter it. If you get a string of errors before you even enter `HELO`, u-b-broken.. ;-/  Upgrade to the most recent stable version of Xamarin.iOS on both machines, and retry. Otherwise contact support.**

**Personally**, I would upgrade to the Xamarin 4.0 for Visual Studio (currently an alpha release) as it replaces the PIN pairing with a SSH tunnel that avoids all of the older issues with 3.0 Build Host connection problems.

Re: http://developer.xamarin.com/releases/vs/xamarin.vs_4/xamarin.vs_4.0/

> This version also introduces the new Xamarin Mac Agent which replaces
>   the old Xamarin Build Host with a new approach taking advantage of the
>   built-in MacOS Remote Login feature based on SSH for a faster and more
>   reliable connectivity.

[Build Host Troubleshooting](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/troubleshooting/)

[Additional build host connection troubleshooting steps](https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/1733609-additional-build-host-connection-troubleshooting-steps)

Comment: okay , I will try tommorow dude. Thank's. I will reply you if it will help me

Answer (score 0):

Very very strange issue. The answer is ElCapitan. 
After many attempts, research, network analysis, packet analysis, firewalls behavior, I noticed that the requests from Windows to OSX not arrived. I upgraded to ElCapitan, and I was able to connect to the Mac with amazing speed.